# Inject content script into iframe inside background.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible?

I want to do this so I can *kinda* fake the origin/host header, when sending a XHR from background.html.
I could make it open a new tab or a popup and inject the code into that, however that is not desirable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Why do you need to inject a "content script" into an iframe in a background page, could it not just be from JavaScript in the background page? Are you aware that content scripts can now make cross-domain XHR requests?

Comment: @AdamAyres I know that, however the site checks for the host and origin http headers, which can't be faked in Chrome. If I could access the iframe, Chrome will send the correct origin and host http headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regretably, you cannot.
executeScript is a tab's method.  Your frame has to be in a tab in order to inject your content script in it.

Answer (score 0):

If your content script is specified in the manifest with `"allFrames": true`, it will be injected when you create an iframe anywhere, even in the background page.

Note that it may be hard to talk to it: `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` won't work for the same reason as YoArgentino's answer. But the content script can initiate the connection on its own, with, say, `chrome.runtime.connect`.